# RxSwift) Subscribing one observable two time not working

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, rx-swift

### Observable Codes

```swift
private let reviewPublish = PublishSubject<Review>()

var review$: Observable<Review> {
    return reviewPublish.asObservable()
}
```

### Publishing Code

```swift
DB_REVIEWS.observe(.value){ snapShot in
    for child in snapShot.children {
        guard let snap = child as? DataSnapshot else { return }
        guard let data = snap.value as? [String: Any] else { return }
                
        var review = Review()
        review = self.changeDictionaryToReview(data, snap.key)
        self.reviewPublish.onNext(review)
   }
   self.reviewPublish.onCompleted()
}
```

### Subscribe Code

```swift
DBUtil.shared.review$.subscribe(onNext: {
    self.reviews.append($0)
}).disposed(by: self.disposeBag)
```

### Question

I subscribed when the app was launched. So, getting reviews from the database and storing them in an array succeeded. However, **it cannot be reflected in real time.** After the app is launched, if the user adds a new review, it is not reflected. **"self.reviewPublish.onNext(review)" works, but subscribe code in viewController not work.**

any idea?

Comment: when you call this    self.reviewPublish.onCompleted() on a subject like publish subject, it means that this stream is finished and should be finished, you should'nt call this if you want to keep it alive

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer. Thanks to you, I was able to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the information you gave in the question so far, I would expect the code to look like this rather than what you have:

```
extension Review {
    init(_ data: [String : Any], _ key: String) {
        // store what you need to here
    }
}

func reviews() -> Observable<[Review]> {
    return Observable.create { observer in
        DB_REVIEWS.observe(.value) { snapShot in
            let reviews = snapShot.children.compactMap { (child) -> Review? in
                guard let snap = child as? DataSnapshot else { return nil }
                guard let data = snap.value as? [String: Any] else { return nil }
                return Review(data, snap.key)
            }
            observer.onNext(reviews)
        }
        return Disposables.create { /* stop observing here */ }
    }
}
```

There is no reason at all it add a Publisher to the system. I expect there is some way to cancel the observation so put that in the Disposables.create function. If you must put the `reviews` function in a class, the DB_REVIEWS class is as good as any I guess.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Actually, I’m not used to RxSwift yet

Comment: No problem. In general, when you are dealing with a callback closure, wrap it in an Observable.create like I do above and you will be on your way.